# IPython no subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, jupyter-notebook, turtle-graphics

I'm new to IPython but I've programmed a lot in IDLE. Using the Python "turtle" module in Windows, the turtle graphics window freezes up until you get it to start with "no subprocess." This was just a matter of adding "-n" to the shortcut. How can I do this in an IPython notebook? Now it's freezing again.

I'm using WinPython. I haven't found any references online to this problem in IPython yet. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `turtle` module from an ordinary `ipython` console then it should work fine (the same single python process).

`ipython notebook` has no "no subprocess" option -- a web browser doesn't execute Python code (by default) therefore `ipython notebook` uses a server python process to run Python code.

To execute Python code in a browser, you could use [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) e.g., [How to Think Like a Computer Scientist
Learning with Python: Interactive Edition 2.0](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/thinkcspy/index.html). Skulpt supports `turtle` module.